# Como hacer que las propiedades agregadas a un objeto con Object.defineProperty se muestren al agregar el objeto a un arreglo

Tags: javascript

**Estoy tratando de hacer esto:** estoy recorriendo un `array` con un `forEach` 
para agregar un numero indefinido de propiedades a un objeto que luego de ser llenado voy a agregar a un `array` de objetos. este objeto de forma predeterminada tiene dos atributos.

**El problema es:** que al agregar el objeto al `array`, este no contiene las propiedades que le agregue en el `forEach` con el `Object.defineProperty`

Este es mi código

```
function actionSave() {
let ventas = getLSVentas();
let ticketContainer = document.getElementById('ticketContainer');
let productsSell = Array.from(ticketContainer.children);
let total = document.getElementById('result').textContent;

let venta = {
    timeOfSale: new Date(), 
    total: total
}

productsSell.forEach((product,index) => {

    let name = product.children[0].children[0].textContent;
    let price = product.children[2].children[0].textContent;
    let quantity = product.children[3].children[1].textContent;

    Object.defineProperty(venta, `product${index}`, {value: {
        name: name,
        price: price,
        quantity: quantity
    }});
});
console.log(venta);

ventas.push(venta);


localStorage.setItem('ventas', JSON.stringify(ventas))

closePopSave();   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de `value`, el *descriptor de datos* admite otras propiedades; entre ellas, `enumerable`. Que, por defecto, se establece como `false`.

Simplemente, establece esa propiedad como `true`:

```
venta = Object.defineProperty( venta, `product${index}`, {
  value: {
    name: name,
    price: price,
    quantity: quantity
  },
  enumerable: true
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

El metodo "defineProperty" devuelve el objeto modificado por lo tanto deberías de recibirlo y sobrescribir tu variable.

```
venta = Object.defineProperty(venta, `product${index}`, {value: {
    name: name,
    price: price,
    quantity: quantity
}});
```

Documentacion: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/defineProperty